# DLL HMODULE for Windows Mobile DLL

Tags: dll, windows-mobile

I am creating a DLL for Windows Mobile 6.x. I need to obtain HMODULE of my own DLL, but so far I haven't been successful. For standard Windows DLLs this seems to be quite simple, as `DllMain` signature is:

`BOOL DllMain(HMODULE, DWORD, LPVOID)`

And you can just take the first parameter and save it in a global variable. However signature for Windows Mobile DLLs is (for reasons I don't understand):

`BOOL DllMain(HANDLE, DWORD, LPVOID)`

Where or how do I get HMODULE for my DLL in such case?
Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That HANDLE *is* the HMODULE.  They both are typedefed from `void *`.

**EDIT**

I just tested this and it worked as expected:

```
#include "windows.h"


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    HMODULE module = (HMODULE)hModule;
    RETAILMSG(TRUE, (_T("module = 0x%08x\r\n", module));

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: No they aren't in Windows Mobile SDK. Excerpts from winnt.h:

`typedef void *HANDLE;
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__ { int unused; }; typedef struct name##__ *name`

and from windef.h:

`DECLARE_HANDLE(HINSTANCE);
typedef HINSTANCE HMODULE;`

This code throw error during compilation:

`HMODULE module;
HANDLE handle;
module = handle;`

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910684.aspx: "The HINSTANCE of a DLL is the same as the HMODULE of the DLL, so hinstDLL can be used in subsequent calls to the GetModuleFileName function and other functions that require a module handle.". While it's not following the C or C++ rules, you can most likely safely cast between these two types. The struct based declarations are there to prevent code from doing this by accident (eg confusing HWNDs with HANDLEs).

Comment: Could you please clarify how should I cast? Using both **module = (HMODULE)handle;** and **module = reinterpret_cast<HMODULE>(handle);** I end up with NULL value in module, while handle wasn't NULL.

Comment: @Omikr0n I would be very surprised if that were the case, although it is possible. I would expect both of those to work. I have seen behavior like this with certain optimizations (the compiler is free to assume no aliasing between unrelated types) but that was with gcc and not MSVC. How are you determining that module is NULL and handle isn't? Are you sure that is correct? Have you tried disassembling DllMain? If it is the case that the code gen is indeed the problem you can work around it by punning with a union (or disabling that class of optimization). I would still be surprised though.

Comment: I'm with Logan.  I'd just direct cast it, and I've never seen that fail.

Comment: Actually my entire problem seemed to be that VS debugger was lying to me. I was checking the value after conversion only by debugger watch and it always shown 0. However condition **module == NULL** is FALSE. So indeed simply converting HANDLE to HMODULE works. Thank you very much for your patience and help.